# Excel column fill up from another excel by macro or formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have two different excel sheets. One excel sheet some values which I need to compare some column and if they matches then need to copy that values on another excel sheet. There is lots of rows which cannot be filled manually, so i was thinking of any formula if i can use to copy that.

example :

**SHEET1**
[image]

**SHEET2**
[image]

For example I need to fill orange column (N) in Sheet2 based on the matching combination from Sheet1. If Column C and Column K matches the value in both sheet, then I need to copy the value of Column N from sheet 1 to Sheet 2.

**PS :** the rows in both sheets are not in same orders.

Adding some excel sample for easier output.

```
Sheet1
    Item_code   Item_id Item_name
    AB          011     ABC
    CD          012     PQR
    EE          045     AAS
    DF          015     AAF
    SD          032     DDF
    FG          078     KKJ
    TY          013     NJY

Sheet2
Item_code   Item_id Item_name
TY          013 
SD          032     
CD          012     
DF          015     
AB          011     
FG          078     
EE          045
```

Comment: I recommend using INDEX/MATCH using table references. What are the names of the shown tables?

Comment: hi, could you please elaborate what exactly you meant here. with some examples. as i have added some samples code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=IFERROR(INDEX(SHEET1!N:N,MATCH(1,(SHEET1!C:C=@C:C)*(SHEET1!K:K=@K:K),0)),"")` would give you the desired result. But it's better to use table references (but we don't know the table names).

Older versions of Excel need this formula confirmed with `ctrl+shift+enter`

Comment: your formula is not working, could you take my example code and make your sheet, and give a screenshot. as i have tried. it says invalid function.

Comment: You probably don't have Office365. Then you need to type it like this in `N2` confirmed by `ctrl+shift+enter`: `=IFERROR(INDEX(SHEET1!N:N,MATCH(1,(SHEET1!C:C=C2)*(SHEET1!K:K=K2),0)),"")` and drag the formula down.

Comment: yes, thank you. its working now.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, would an IF statement suffice here? `=IF(AND($C1=Sheet1!$C1,$K1=Sheet1!$K1),Sheet1!$N1,"")`

Comment: could you edit your code as per my example. i have added a sample code which can be copy paste in any excel?

Comment: one more thing the row sequence is not in same order, so C1 in sheet2 is might not same in C1 in sheet1. but in C column that value will be there.

Comment: Right, it looks like you're going to want to create an index. You can do this by creating a new sheet, then having ```=UNIQUE(Sheet1!C:C)``` and then having a VLOOKUP to match those up with the column K values. From there, you could do a VLOOKUP again on your new sheet to match them all up together.